# ¿Tengo una duda sobre el uso de métodos/funciones?

Tags: java, diseño-de-clases

Mi duda es acerca de en que parte se deben de poner los métodos, ya sea en la clase principal donde se encuentra el método main, o en la clase donde se pone el constructor para inicializar  los atributos.

Entiendo el uso de getters y setters, pero por ejemplo estos codigos que la primera foto es de la Cuenta donde va el constructor y el segundo es donde va el metodo main, si se quiere realizar un retiro... No sera más fácil realizarlo desde la clase donde esta el método main?, en este código se utilizaron ambas, pero me confunde un poco en que parte deben de ponerse los métodos. Si en la clase principal o donde se genera el constructor. Apenas inicie en el mundo de la programación.

[image: CUENTA, CONSTRUCTOR]

[image: Metodo principal]

Comment: Recomendaciones: 1. Copia y pega el código en vez de un pantallazo. 2. Como recién estás iniciando, sigue este tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/CatalogJava.htm y a este otro https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm Buena suerte y bienvenido a bordo al mundo del desarrollo de software :D

Answer (score 1):

El método **main** solo es el punto de entrada a su programa. No tiene porque estar pasando continuamente por dicho método.
La clase **cuenta** la puede llamar desde cualquier parte de su programa las veces que sea necesario.
Creo que la confusión se debe a que las clases representan un **objeto del dominio del problema** y no son un agrupamiento de métodos.
Dicha clase representa un objeto cuenta y debería tener solo esa responsabilidad.
Espero le sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Java es un lenguaje de programación [Orientado a Objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos), por lo tanto se intenta representar "objetos" del mundo real y darles un comportamiento. En tu caso Cuenta es una clase que tiene toda la lógica necesaria para manipular la información de una cuenta, protegiendo sus datos y estableciendo una interfaz que define cómo otros objeto pueden interactuar con ella.

El main es unicamente el punto donde arranca tu aplicación, el punto de entrada. Desde allí se debe orquestar los llamados a los objetos que requieras, pero no debe haber allí lógica del negocio. Es decir, para este ejemplo está bien que tengas allí algún ciclo para capturar entradas del usuario, o lo que requieras para obtener la información que requieras para tu programa; pero no deberá tener la lógica que tiene el detalle de que hacer cuando se hace un retiro, por ejemplo. En este caso el main se encarga de llamar a los objetos "especializados" que saben qué hacer con esa información (y cómo hacerlo).

En un ejemplo pequeño esto quizá no parezca tan relevante. Pero, ¿qué pasa en una aplicación más grande dónde no tienes unicamente que realizar acciones sobre cuentas sino también sobre clientes, bancos,  conexiones con base de datos? Eso volvería el proyecto demasiado confuso y dificil de mantener al tener todo en un solo lugar.

Comment: Hola mauricio. Veo que tienes experiencia en la red. Igual te recomiendo leer el [tour]. Bienvenido!

Comment: Hecho. Gracias gbianchi.

Comment: De nada.. es muy probable que la pregunta sea cerrada como basada en opiniones... hay que ver donde conviene, dependiendo de a donde se quiera llegar. Una cosa son las buenas practicas, y otra terminar el trabajo de la uni ;)